# R replace substring with itself and the following word (negation handling)

Tags: r, string, text, replace

I have looked through a couple of answers but they always only answer parts of my problem. I have a vector of negation words and a data frame column with customer reviews. The end-goal is to assign a sentiment to each review by assigning sentiment to its constituting words. As and example, the review `"I was happy with the product"` would have neutral sentiment for all words but `"happy"` which in this case has positive connotation. Now I need to handle negations as they nearly always turn around the sentiment so the review from before but with negative sentiment would be `"I was not happy with the product"`. Obviously it can get more complicated than this.

Assuming I have a vector of negation words `negations` and a vector (data frame column) of `reviews`, how could I scan through the reviews and replace all negation words with their negation, an underscore and the following word, so above example would end up being `"I was not_happy with the product"`. This would allow me to treat the negated word as one (of course I need to adjust my sentiment word corpus accordingly. Note the actual language is not English. I'm assuming I need some complex regex that can reference the matched negation but I'm not a regex pro.

**example**

```
negations <- c("not", "without", "never")
reviews <- c("I was happy", "I never asked", "I came without hope", "He did not help")
```

Outcome should be

```
c("I was happy", "I never_asked", "I came without_hope", "He did not_help")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this from `stringi` package:

```
stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(reviews,
  paste0(negations, " "),
  paste0(negations, "_"), vectorize_all = F)
```

Comment: much easier than I expected. tks.